# Getting 500 when using auto transform validation in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I'm using NestJS and I'm trying to get auto-transform for params to work.
I've added that code:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  }),
);
```

And I have a controller that receives a numeric param:

```
@Get(':id')
getStuff(@Param('id') id: number) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is when I try to use a non numeric param (`path/to/controller/one` instead of `path/to/controller/1`) I receive a 500 Internal Server error instead of the expected 400 response. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValidationPipe` does not work on primitive types (string, boolean, number), so you'll need to use the `ParseIntPipe` or something similar on the `@Param()` decorator to ensure you get the same kind of logic being applied. What's probably happening is something in your service is expecting a number and it's getting a string, and doesn't know how to process it from there.

On option would be to create a DTO for the URL parameters like so

```js
export class ControllerRouteParamDto {
  @Transform(({ value }) => Number.parseInt(value, 10))
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;
}
```

The `@Transform()` is necessary due to url and query parameters coming in as strings and not their related types.

Comment: So enabling the ValidationPipe's auto transform feature means the auto transformed data isn't validated?

Comment: I'll say it again, [primitives are not validated directly](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L145) because there's no class to tell `class-transformer` and `class-validator` about. You can create a DTO class, or follow the [Explicit Conversion](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#explicit-conversion) portion of the docs