# Nestjs ValidationPipe({transform: true}) does not transform string to number for request body

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator, class-transformer

As mentioned in the docs

> The ValidationPipe can automatically transform payloads to be objects typed according to their DTO classes. To enable auto-transformation, set transform to true.

But I always get Bad Request, so the transform doesn't work.

[image: Postman-request body]

validation dto

```typescript
export class CreateDistrictDto {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    name: string;
    
    
    // associations
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber()
    cityId: number;
}
```

route in controller

```typescript
    @Post()
    async createCity(@Body() cityDto: CreateCityDto) {
        return await this.cityService.createCity(cityDto);
    }
```

main.ts (I use default @nestjs/common ValidationPipe)

```typescript
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
}));
```

This answer says that transform doesn't work for primitives, which seems to be true.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67181540/8419307
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L137

Then why does the docs say otherwise and what is the transform: true option for?

Comment: Is this for a body, a query, a url parameter? What does a sample payload/url look like?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel this is for body. I have added more info to the question.

Answer (score 20):

So it appears that `body-parser` is not transforming the number into a number implicitly. To get around this, either send in a JSON request (`application/json`) with an explicit number or enable implicit type conversion in the `class-transformer` options via `transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },` in the `ValidationPipe` options.

```js
{
  provide: APP_PIPE,
  useValue: new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
  }),
},
```

Comment: at the risk of invoking the wrath of the stackoverflow gods... thank you! Saved me a lot of time - wish I'd found this earlier

Comment: why isn't this a default option? Same with transform true... this brings lots of bugs and issue when working with nest..

Comment: Why is this not mentioned in nest docs?? Seems important

Answer (score 6):

For transform the value you need to use `@Transform()` of [`class-transform`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/class-transformer) module, for instance:

```js
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateProductDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    return Number(value);
  })
  pieces: number;
}
```